# ssh key issue connecting to github via remote machine

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am having some issues with using git (github) on a remotely accessed machine.  I am logging in from home into my work computer via ssh e.g.

```
me@home$ ssh me@work
```

after which I try to do a pull or push request to github on my work computer via home e.g.

```
me@workViaHome$ git pull origin branch
```

after which I receive the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried loading the ssh key from my work computer using:

```
me@workViaHome$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
me@workViaHome$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but still no luck.  When I am physically at my work computer I can issue requests to github without any issues; so it seems the issue with with the status of my ssh-keys due to my ssh session.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Verify that the private key you've added on workViaHome is actually the right one for the public key you've added on github. Also verify that the access permissions for the ~/.ssh directory are correct. Finally, try to ssh to github using the same user/port as git, and add the verbose flag to get more info.

Comment: So I isolated the issue to ssh-add not triggering git to use the ~/.ssh/id_rsa key, it was still trying to use the default key.  I cheated for now in that I added the default key to github and it works.  I used ssh -vT git@github.com to figure it out.  I'm still not sure why ssh kept falling back to the default key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH is using the default keys if it is not specified otherwise in configuration or if the `ssh-agent` is not providing any other key.

If you are using a key in nonstandard location, that you have added in your `gnome-keyring`, you could notice this behavior, because `gnome-keying` starts only for the graphical sessions, but not for `ssh` sessions.

Certainly, you can resolve this by properly configuring this key in `~/.ssh/config` on the work computer. Just add

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/path_to_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```